# Magento Extension Installation in my theme

Tags: magento, php

I was searching for a contact form for my website design on magento platform. I installed a quick contact magento extension, that extension is working well with the default theme/design of magento.

But i want this to work with my custom theme which I installed. How can i do that so it starts working with my current package/theme.

I have checked and found the current form.phtml is stored in app/design/frontend/default.default/template/quickcontact/form.phtml

My current theme is Shopcrown

Comment: move the template and layout files from `default` to your theme.

Comment: I have moved the Layout file from /public_html/app/design/frontend/default/default/layout
to
/public_html/app/design/frontend/shopcrown/default/layout
and template from 
/public_html/app/design/frontend/default/default/template
to
/public_html/app/design/frontend/shopcrown/default/template
but it is still not showing up.

Comment: Check if the extension has to be enabled in store view level in backend.

Comment: have you seen this extension under system -> configuration -> advanced ?